# How to pipe the each output of grep to another command?

Tags: shell, grep, xargs

I have a command the returns a list of tables in the database:

`drush sqlq "show tables"|grep deleted`

This returns a list of tables that need to be removed:

```
field_deleted_data_811d267471
field_deleted_data_e52abfde52
field_deleted_data_eefd3bb8fd
```

I am trying to take each result line and pipe in into a command

`drush sqlq "drop table TABLENAME"`

I am trying to build somehting like 
`drush sqlq "show tables"|grep deleted |xargs -n1 drush sqlq "drop table ${TABLE_NAME}"` where `TABLE_NAME` each line of the output.

I [saw the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input) but it still remains unclear how you can access each result line in the piped command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs` has `-I<STRING>` that will be replaced before running the command, in your case would be e.g.:

```
drush sqlq "show tables"|grep deleted |xargs -I@ -n1 drush sqlq "drop table @"
```